# Ubuntu 13.10 GNOME: visual glitch when hovering over icons

Tags: gnome, visual-artifacts, ubuntu-gnome

I recently installed Ubuntu GNOME 13.10, and this is the only obvious issue so far. Every time I hover over an icon of any sort, a pixelated green glitch occurs on the icon that the mouse is hovering over. I am baffled by this issue, as it doesn't seem like anyone has asked a question relating to this issue before. Someone please help! Further details can be provided.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
```

Comment: Please open the terminal and run the command: `lspci -nn | grep VGA` and add the results of this command to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, dell e7440:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b). I get the glitch hovering over icons and corrupted pixels while scrolling in the preview pane in thunderbird as well. I have a xps14 that is ivy bridge and it definitely does not have the same corrupt video issue.